# http PUT a file to S3 presigned URLs using ruby

Tags: ruby, http, amazon-s3

Anyone got a working example of using ruby to post to a presigned URL on s3

Comment: Please post the solution you found.

Answer (score 2):

I have used aws-sdk and right_aws both.

Here is the code to do this.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'aws-sdk'
require 'right_aws'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'
require 'rack'


access_key_id     = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
secret_access_key = 'ASDFASDFAS4646ASDFSAFASDFASDFSADF'


s3 = AWS::S3.new(  :access_key_id => access_key_id, :secret_access_key => secret_access_key)

right_s3 = RightAws::S3Interface.new(access_key_id,  secret_access_key,  {:multi_thread => true, :logger => nil} ) 



bucket_name = 'your-bucket-name'
key  = "your-file-name.ext"

right_url = right_s3.put_link(bucket_name, key)
right_scan_command = "curl -I --upload-file #{key} '#{right_url.to_s}'"
system(right_scan_command)

bucket = s3.buckets[bucket_name]
form = bucket.presigned_post(:key => key)
uri = URI(form.url.to_s + '/' + key)
uri.query = Rack::Utils.build_query(form.fields)
scan_command = "curl -I --upload-file #{key} '#{uri.to_s}'"
system(scan_command)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more information on how a "presigned URL" works?  Is it like this:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for(self.full_filename,
                          self.bucket_name, {
                            :use_ssl => true,
                            :expires_in => ttl_seconds
                          })
```

I use this code to send authenticated clients the URL to their S3 file.  I believe this is the "presigned URL" that you're asking about.  I haven't used this code for a PUT, so I'm not exactly sure if it's right for you, but it might get you close.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question, but I was wondering the same thing and found an elegant solution in the [AWS S3 Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLRubySDK.html).

```
require 'net/http'

file = "somefile.ext"
url = URI.parse(presigned_url)
Net::HTTP.start(url.host) do |http|
   http.send_request("PUT", url.request_uri, File.read(file), {"content-type" => "",})
end
```

This worked great for my Device Farm uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Does anything on the [s3 library page](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) cover what you need?  There are loads of examples there.

Comment: Unfortunately not. And the RUBY S3 Gems don;t support the signed urls

Answer (score 0):

There are some generic REST libraries for Ruby; Google for "ruby rest client".  See also [HTTParty](http://railstips.org/2008/7/29/it-s-an-httparty-and-everyone-is-invited).

Answer (score -5):

I've managed to sort it out. Turns out the HTTP:Net in Ruby is has some short comings. Lot of Monkeypatch later I got it working.. More details when I have time. thank

Comment: Provide the solution then. Otherwise Stack Overflow doesn't work. :)